# Horizontally merging arrays in GAS / JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I've got couple arrays I want to horizontally merge:

```
data1 =   [["ID"], [21], [26], [32]]

data2 = [["A", "B", "C"],[10, 10, 10], [95, 95, 95], [95, 95, 95]]
```

Both array always have the same number of "rows"

I'm looking for this result:

```
result = [["ID", "A" , "B", "C"],[21, 10, 10, 10]...]
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ ) {
  data3.push( [ data1[i], data2[i] ] );
}
```

Which is giving me a strange result and I don't really understand why.

[[["A"], [10, 10 ,10]]]

Any help? I always struggle with Arrays.

Comment: What are `A, B, C`? If variables, they are undefined in your code.

Comment: Sorry, miss that. They're strings actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a weird result. 
To achieve what you need, please try this

```
 data3.push( data2[i].unshift(data1[i][0]) );
```

Assumption: A, B, C are Strings, like 'A'

Suggestion: You should follow a better datastructure. but still try the below solution. Array index starts from 1. You kept on changing the question, and I need to update my answer accordingly. I tried the below, it works for me.

```
var data1 = [["ID"], [21], [26], [32]];

var data2 = [["A", "B", "C"],[10, 10, 10], [95, 95, 95], [95, 95, 95]];

var data3 = [];

  for ( var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++ ) {
      data2[i].unshift(data1[i][0]);
      data3.push(data2[i] );
    }
 console.log(data3)
```

Gives me the following output

```
[["ID","A","B","C"], [21, 10, 10, 10], [26, 95, 95, 95] ,[32, 95, 95, 95]]
```

Comment: Not really working, I get a big array with the same value over an over. Any idea why?

Comment: please find a new solution

Comment: It doesn't work, but I've realized my Array examples and my question was not very clear to be fair! Sorry about that I've improved it.